# Inherited functions to return Derived class, not Base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is it possible in C++ to formulate functions in the Base class that return Base type such that in the Derived class, they return Derived type, without overloading?

Minimal example:

```
class Base
{
    public:
        Base(double v)
        {
            value = v;
        }

        Base add(Base b)
        {
            return Base(b.value + this->value);
        }

        void print()
        {
            std::cout << value << std::endl;
        }

        double value;
};



class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived(double v) : Base(v)
        {

        }

        void timesTwo()
        {
            value *= 2.0;
        }
};


int main()
{

    Derived d1(1), d2(2);

    // This doesn't work because the result is of type Base
    (d1.add(d2)).timesTwo();


    return 0;
}
```

## Motivation

In the actual example, `Base` represents a linear algebra matrix, and `Derived` represents a vector. The matrix offers many functions that are all applicable to vectors, such as addition or multiplication by a scalar.

In this case, it would be desirable not having to override all these matrix functions manually to return vectors. I would like to, if possible, express that whatever `this` type is, the return type should be identical to it.

Example:

```
class Matrix
{
    ...
    Matrix operator*(double x);
};

class Vector : Matrix
{
    ...
};

Matrix M;
M = M * 2.0; // works

Vector v;
v = v * 2.0; // does not work, because v * 2.0 returns a Matrix
```

The effort for overriding e.g. `operator*()` for all derived classes is increased by the fact that there are derived classes for 3- and 2-dimensional vectors, etc.

I understand that a solution is to define a cast from `Matrix` to `Vector` (and to `Vector3`, `Vector2`, ...) but this would involve copying all entries (which are, for efficiency, stack arrays).

Is there a more efficient solution? And, if not, would it generally be considered cleaner/better to

1. duplicate all the relevant code in each derived class, or to
2. define a cast?

In my current understanding, the conflicting problems are:

1. Duplicate code makes the solution error-prone and more difficult to refactor.
2. Reusing existing code requires lots of copy operations every time the "scope" changes between Matrix, Vector, Vector3, ... . Would be inefficient if used in large calculations.

Any suggestion would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have look at [CRTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: I think that would be an anti-pattern.

Comment: You could make the operations virtual instead, so that you would just use polymorphism. But that would suggest using Java or C# in the first place.

Comment: Please look up "covariant return types". Having said that, `class Vector : Matrix` is not the best of ideas, despite its initial appeal.

Comment: @szpanczyk: if CRTP is an anti pattern, most of MTP code is bad design :-)

Comment: I was referring to the conceept of base class being aware of derived classes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but only with free functions (including most operators).

```
template<class X, class Y,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base, std::decay_t<X>>{},int> =0,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base, std::decay_t<Y>>{},int> =0
>
friend X& operator+=(X&x, Y&& rhs)
{
  x.value += rhs.value;
  return x.
}
template<class X, class Y,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base, std::decay_t<X>>{},int> =0,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base, std::decay_t<Y>>{},int> =0
>
friend std::decay_t<X> operator+(X&&x, Y&& rhs) {
  auto r=std::forward<X>(x);
  r+=std::forward<Y>(rhs);
  return r;
}
```

Now if I did that right,

```
(d1+d2).timesTwo();
```

works.

I also implemented `+` in terms of `+=` because that usually works well.

The fancy enable if exists because koenig lookup with very generic template operators causes strange things to happen when you pass `Base` and types derived from `Base` to template types and proceed to use `+` on the resulting type.  By saying "only things derived from `Base`", the right thing happens.

We need to use a template free friend function so we can get the type of "`*this`" (as it where) within the template to change our return type.  This cannot be done in a template member function.

The `enable_if` clause does not work well in MSVC, but is best practice in other compilers.  For MSVC use `class=enable_if` instead of `enable_if=0`.  The reason why the `=0` is best is out of scope here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, I believe that was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Make class Base abstract and put its methods in separated functions. Also declare pure virtual the methods you need in derived classes:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base(double v) : value(v) {}

    double value;
    virtual void timesTwo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(double v) : Base(v) {}

    void timesTwo()
    {
        value *= 2.0;
        std::cout << "timesTwo " << value << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T>
T add(const T& t1, const T& t2)
{
    return T(t1.value + t2.value);
}

int main()
{
    Derived d1(1), d2(2);
    add(d1, d2).timesTwo();

    return 0;
}
```