# Is there any way to get derived_class type from it's object (not reference to derived_class)

Tags: c++

There is Log history of commands in any command language with changable state. Each Command is object that is added to Log when Run. Log is one of fields of State of language. Each Command needs to know unique State to be able to Run. State is common for all commands in Log. So, it would be logical to push std::unique_ptr<Command> to Log, because, outside of Log, Command does not make any sense and inside Log each Command exists in unique example in unique place. In conclusion, it would be helpful to have one method in Command that does all job (in my code it is "SetRunGet"), which polimorphically does not depend of specific derived Command type. I don't want to make_unique with specific derived class every time i need to create Command and spend code space for it. But. If I make class Command abstract, I won't be able to create unique_ptr. So there are are two ways: first - to define SetRunGet in every Derived Command (first minus - a lot of code, second minus - a lot of duplicate code), second (which is not achieved yet) - force Command to be not-abstract, define all it's methods in any, maybe sensless, way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Command {
public:
    Command() = default;
    virtual void Run(){
        std::cout << "I'm Command and I don't have any sense except saving Command from being abstract" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Command> SetRunGet() {

        decltype(this) stuff = this; // type here is DerivedCommand*
        decltype(*this) stuff1 = *this; // type here is DerivedCommand&
        std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type anotherstuff = *this; // type is std::remove_reference<Command&>::type

        // all other stuff that is done only once, for example creating
        // and setting inverted Command to be done when Undo using virtual Inverted method
        // and/or setting State which contains Log
        Run();
        return std::make_unique<std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type>(*this);
    }
    virtual void PrintType(){
        std::cout << "Base Command" << std::endl;
    };
};

class DerivedCommand : public Command {
public:
    DerivedCommand() = default;
    void Run() override {
        std::cout << "I'm Derived Command, Hi" << std::endl;
    }
    void PrintType() override {
        std::cout << "Derived Command" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Log {
public:
    Log() = default;
    void Push(std::unique_ptr<Command> command){
        log_.push_back(std::move(command));
    };
    std::unique_ptr<Command>& Get(size_t position){
        return log_[position];
    };
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Command>> log_{};
};

int main(){
    Log log{};
    DerivedCommand command{};
    log.Push(command.SetRunGet());
    auto& command_after_push = log.Get(0);
    command_after_push->PrintType(); // here prints "Base Command"
}
```

So the problem is to extract Derived Command type (not reference to Derived Command). I have searched much, also on stackoverflow, but the only thing at least partly close to my problem was this question: [Inherited functions to return Derived class, not Base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652069/inherited-functions-to-return-derived-class-not-base-class). And solution, that was suggested seems to be very rude and illegal (i' m about the first answer, not about last solution where it is suggested to make class abstract, what is not my way, i want to create unique_ptr in Command).

If it is not possible to extract type from type&, i would like to know about why either. If so, it is very strange for me, thus we can get DerivedCommand&, then why not DerivedCommand.

If there is another way to solve this problem without any duplicate (calling std::make_unique<Some Derived Command>(args) is also duplicate for me) every time i want to Push, I would like to know it either.

Accept advices about approach, for example, I suppose, it is not logical conclusion that Command in Log should be unique_ptr. Maybe there is common and at least partly clean invented "wheel", to solve problem. Macro does not seem to be clean, maybe I'm not right.

Thanks.

Comment: C++ does not work this way, on a fundamental level. In C++ the types of all objects must be specified at compile-time. There is no runtime reflection in C++.

Comment: I feel like your question starts in the middle of the story -- like I'm expected to already know what you're talking about. Could you start with an abstract introduction to your scenario, proceed to your requirements, *then* maybe describe your concrete case with "Log history" and "any command language"?

Comment: can Push be templated? then the solution is trivial.

Comment: `virtual std::string WhoAmI() const { return "DerivedCommand"; }`